# Loop through Model properties in reflection, then use Html helpers to display. How to get concrete property back?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

We have an MVC4 ASP.Net site that we are trying to use reflection to loop through properties of a model, and display the names/values/and other information using Html helpers.

We have a custom Html Helper that we are passing in arguments from the method below.

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        Html.LabelFor( ?? Any ideas ?? )
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @SuperEditorFor.ReflectiveEditorFor(prop, Model)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name))
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

We have tried putting in the "property" (quote) as in the `ValidationMessageFor` but as we suspected, it wants the actual concrete property, not the reflection propertyInfo object.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Has anyone tried to do this before?

Comment: Why would you not just use `Html.Label(prop.Name)` and `@Html.ValidationMessage(prop.Name)`?

Comment: Does this still use the attributes on the model for validations? like `[Required]`

Comment: Yeah it uses the same method in the end.  The For methods just use linq expressions to pull the property name.

Comment: I think you'd have to create the `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` the LabelFor() and ValidationMessageFor() expect manually in order for this to work. Not impossible. A larger concern is how fast the page will render with all of that reflection going on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use generic implementations for that (`EditorFor`, `DisplayFor`...), just use the non generic ones, `Editor`, `Display`...

This will work just fine, you will get validation, automatic bindings and everything else, the whole nine yards...

```
@foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label(prop.Name)
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.Editor(prop.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If you want to experiment with generic implementations here is a great blog post on how to do that

http://www.joelscode.com/use-mvc-templates-with-dynamic-generated-types-with-custom-htmlhelper-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not possible the way you want it.
Try to use this instead :

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```