# How to show DisplayName and value of each property in Model dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In some cases when properties is more than usual it is painful to copy and past some code after another to show all properties of a Model , So I want to know is there a way to show all properties of a Model dynamically.
for example, we have this TestModel:

```
TestModel.cs
[Display(Name = "نام")]
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "ایمیل")]
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "شماره تماس")]
[Required]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Now I want to show both DisplayName and Value of this Model in razor, for example sth like this:

```
TestRazor.cshtml
@foreach (var Item in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   <div class="row">
   <p class="label">@Item.DisplayName</p>
   <p class="value">@Item.Value</p>
   </div>
   <br />
   <br />
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the display name and value of each property like this:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using System.Reflection

@foreach (var item in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
        var label = item.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name;
        var value = item.GetValue(Model);
        <div class="row">
            <p class="label">@label</p>
            <p class="value">@value</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
}
```

Comment: compile time error : system.reflection.propertyinfo dos not contain a definition fot GetCustomAttribute

Comment: You need those two namespaces above `@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`
`@using System.Reflection`

Comment: excuse me, although I pressed right click on error for find resolve option but didnt exist. thank U for your answer @alisabzevari.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use helpers `@Html.EditorForModel()` and `@Html.DisplayForModel()`. You can read about them [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm).

This helpers generate edit and view temlate that shows all your model properties and attributes by default.

But if you want to change default html that generate this method you can easily create your own `EditorTemplates` and `DisplayTemplates` if you want to change HTML for whoule model or use `UIHint` Attribute if you need to change View for just some properties.

In you case on your view just write `@Html.DisplayForModel()` and you will get all properties of your model

Comment: No, I escape from using something like @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name) becouse you mention "Name" , It isnt dynamic as I know.

Comment: Don't you mention that i write `EditorForModel` not `EditorFor` **editor for Whole model**? You don't need to write properties.

Comment: It isnt what I want, please explain more , I cant find my answer in your mentiond website.

Comment: Thank U , answer of @alisabzevari is complete I think